# Test whether the GPS data been deleted

Tags: android, gps, gpsd

I have written a code in C (sending commands to phone) to delete GPS data (eph, alm, time, position etc) on LG Phoenix phone and i am trying to test if the data has been deleted. What would be the best way to test it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response helpful, please upvote it. If a particular response answers your question adequately, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call last the [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) on the GPS provider and see if it returns anything.

Comment: i tried that.. but it doesn't seem to be helping. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: once i delete all the GPS data ...the time taken to get first fix is more but i always get the location (may be cached pos) but after deletion number of satellites user for fix will be zero. I know that my code is working but donno how to prove that.

Comment: Actually [`getLastKnownLocation()`](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java.shtml) returns the last known location cached at the application layer, whereas s/he's cleaned out the satellite tracing data at the chipset level.

Comment: yes I get it now... thts the reason lastknownlocation is returned even after I delete GPS data. So how can I prove that tracing data is getting cleared now?

Answer (score 0):

Different GPS chipsets stores this data in different locations, so you can never be sure. I don't know what chipset is used in your LG phone. Root your phone and browse the `/data/` directory, usually you'll find something like `/data/gps/`.

The external symptoms of deleting this data is that of a cold start. That is, if the device is not connected to the internet, and it is somewhere outside, it will take 2 minutes or longer to get a GPS fix. So that's how you'l know.